# The maximum number of rows each time I can insert to a table in database using pandas.DataFrame.to_sql

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` method to write the DataFrame to a sqlite database. According to the helping page in [DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), the **chunksize** parameter can control number of rows we want to insert to a table, when it is None(default), all the rows will be inserted at once. So I think the number of rows we can inserted may be unlimited, just like the number of rows in a table is unlimited, just depend on the size of your disk.

While, when I using this method, I find I can't insert too many rows at once (I can append little piece data gradually), sometimes the maximum number of row is 50,000, sometimes is 100,000(different columns), I wonder know whether there are limited to the size of the DataFrame object we want to insert to a table, how to calculate the maximum number of row we can insert to a table at once?

Thanks for all your reply.^_^
[image: the error message]

```
def write_db(data, table_name, db_name):
    """write DataFrame to sqlite database

    :type data: pandas.DataFrame
    :type table_name: str
    :type db_name: str
    :return: None
    """
    maximum_rows = 50000
    loop = divmod(data.shape[0], maximum_rows)[0]
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///{}.db".format(db_name))
    for i in range(loop):
        data_part = data.iloc[i*maximum_rows:(i+1)*maximum_rows, :]
        data_part.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, index=False,
                         index_label="entity_name", if_exists="append")
    data_left = data.iloc[loop*maximum_rows:, :]
    data_left.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, index=False,
                     index_label="entity_name", if_exists="append")
```

Comment: Please do not post error messages and code and data as images

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your code. And perhaps some clue about the data such that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: @KayWittig I have added the code sample, currently, I insert 50,000 rows at once, that's OK. But for more rows, like 50,001, It will be errors.